# accessing value passed from lexer in the parser file

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc, lex

I have a simple config file as shown below

```
[main]
e_type=0x1b
```

In my lex file (test.l) when I encounter token `e_type` I call the following function and retunr `T_E_TYPE` token.

```
void tag ()  {
    yylval.str = malloc(strlen(yytext)+1);
    strcpy (yylval.str, yytext);
}
```

In the parser file (test.y) I have declared the union as follows.

```
%union {
   char *str;
   unsigned int n;
}
```

I am able to recognize `[main]` and `e_type` but If I try to print `yylval.str` from `test.y` file I get a segmentation fault.

How can I access the values I passed from lexer in the test.y file.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `yylval` corresponding to each token has been pushed onto the stack, and is available in the reduction rule as `$n` for some `n` (the symbols on the right hand side are numbered in order). You must declare the type-tag of each token so that bison knows which member of the union to use.